# Dynamic tables with JavaScript KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Hello I'm trying to create a Dynamic table for input values using Knockout.
The table later will work like a data matrix, so I can multiplicate the input value of the "product brands".

This is what a have for now:

```js
 
        var Group = function(brand,value) {
            this.brand = ko.observable(brand);
        };

      var ViewModel = function(groups) {
            var self = this;
     
         self.optionValues_brand = ko.observableArray(["Brand1","Brand2","Brand3"]);
            self.selectedBrand = ko.observable();
          
          self.groups = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(groups, function(group) {
                return new Group(group.brand);
            }));

          
          self.addGroup = function() {
            self.groups.push(new Group(self.selectedBrand()));
          }
      }
      
      var initialGroups = [];
       
        var viewModel = new ViewModel(initialGroups);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Brand:</td>
      <td><select data-bind="options: optionValues_brand, optionsCaption: 'Select One...', value:       selectedBrand"></select></td>

      <td><button data-bind="click: addGroup">Add</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>


<div>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr data-bind="foreach: groups">
        <th></th>
        <th data-bind="text: brand"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: groups">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: brand"></td>
      <td><input type="number" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that I need that all columns and rows  to have an input field, but only one column is beeing filled with a input field.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypw79dnv/

How to insert the input fields in all columns and rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs aren't bound to any variables, and you haven't made any for them to be bound to, so although we could make the table fill up the way you want, I don't think it would be useful to you.

You need to make a matrix of observables. Each time you add a group, you add a new row to the matrix, and add a new input on the end of each row. It's a bit tricky to keep straight, but you will then be able to cross-reference all your values.

```js
var Group = function(brand, value) {
  this.brand = ko.observable(brand);
};

var ViewModel = function(groups) {
  var self = this;

  self.optionValues_brand = ko.observableArray(["Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3"]);
  self.selectedBrand = ko.observable();

  self.groups = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(groups, function(group) {
    return new Group(group.brand);
  }));
  self.matrix = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.addGroup = function() {
    // Add new row to matrix
    var newRow = ko.observableArray();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.groups(), function(group) {
      newRow.push(ko.observable());
    });
    self.matrix.push(newRow);
    self.groups.push(new Group(self.selectedBrand()));
    // Add group to each row in matrix
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.matrix(), function(row) {
      row.push(ko.observable());
    });
  };
  self.matrix.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.debug("Matrix:", newValue.length, newValue[0]().length);
  });
}

var initialGroups = [];

var viewModel = new ViewModel(initialGroups);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Brand:</td>
    <td>
      <select data-bind="options: optionValues_brand, optionsCaption: 'Select One...', value:       selectedBrand"></select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <button data-bind="click: addGroup">Add</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <!-- ko foreach: groups -->
        <th data-bind="text: brand"></th>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: groups">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: brand"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.matrix()[$index()]() -->
        <td>
          <input type="number" data-bind="value:$data" />
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```